# catch contents generated during run by subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to catch contents generated during the run instead of output since I realized that the output from program is unfortunately not the useful information.

basically my code:

```
command = "usearch11 -threads 8 -fastq_filter pmFLP.fastq -fastq_maxee 1  -fastq_minlen 120 -fastq_maxns 0  -fastaout S1--1.QC.fasta"
with Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True) as process:
    output = process.stdout.readlines()
    print(output)
```

and what is displayed in the terminal after/during running the code:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\Daten\test_Ordner>python test.py
00:00 4.6Mb  FASTQ base 33 for file pmFLP.fastq
00:01 5.3Mb   100.0% Filtering, 98.6% passed
    188650  Reads (188.7k)
      1297  Discarded read with > 0 Ns
      1132  Discarded reads with expected errs > 1.00
    185957  Filtered reads (186.0k, 98.6%)
b'usearch v11.0.667_win64, 137Gb RAM, 64 cores\r\n(C) Copyright 2013-18 Robert C. Edgar, all rights reserved.\r\nhttps://drive5.com/usearch\r\n\r\nLicense: kleine@planton.de\r\n\r\n'
```

and this part is what i need:

```
00:00 4.6Mb  FASTQ base 33 for file pmFLP.fastq
    00:01 5.3Mb   100.0% Filtering, 98.6% passed
        188650  Reads (188.7k)
          1297  Discarded read with > 0 Ns
          1132  Discarded reads with expected errs > 1.00
        185957  Filtered reads (186.0k, 98.6%)
```

any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problably need to catch `stderr` instead of `stdout`. Also I recommend using `subprocess.run()` not `subprocess.Popen()`:

```py
command = "usearch11 -threads 8 -fastq_filter pmFLP.fastq -fastq_maxee 1  -fastq_minlen 120 -fastq_maxns 0  -fastaout S1--1.QC.fasta"
completed_process = run(command, stderr=PIPE, shell=True, text=True)
desired_text = completed_process.stderr
print(desired_text)
```

If you want raw bytes instead, remove the `text=True` flag:

```py
command = "usearch11 -threads 8 -fastq_filter pmFLP.fastq -fastq_maxee 1  -fastq_minlen 120 -fastq_maxns 0  -fastaout S1--1.QC.fasta"
completed_process = run(command, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
desired_text = completed_process.stderr  # Those are now bytes, not str!
print(desired_text)
```

To write the output to a binary file:

```py
command = "usearch11 -threads 8 -fastq_filter pmFLP.fastq -fastq_maxee 1  -fastq_minlen 120 -fastq_maxns 0  -fastaout S1--1.QC.fasta"

with open("summary.txt", "wb") as file:
    run(command, stderr=file, shell=True)
```

As you can see, you can also pass any writable file object to `stderr` or `stdout`.

Comment: thanks a lot that works!!! but i have another question.. i would like than write the desired test into a txt file and i run following codes `    with open("summary.txt","wb") as file:
        for line in desired_text:
            file.write(line)`, but an TypeError pop up : TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'